# How to edit the SUBMIT button in review tab in woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce

I having a problem where to edit the submit button in review tab in woocommerce, I can't even trace it in the backend code. Could somebody help me.

Answer (score 2):

The submit button code is in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php`. You can search for `'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),` Usual line number is 70.

But don't edit the file directly as it will interfere with future WooCommerce upgrades and delete your modification.

You can copy the file and paste it as `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php` and modify the `'Submit'` text to your preference.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question.  I want to add a class to the submit button.  Searching "label_submit" through the entire plugin code base doesn't bring up anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce actually uses the built in Comment Form functionality provided by Wordpress. This explains why it was not traceable in the code.

Here is the [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).

I needed to add classes to the button, so I modified the array in my themes `woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php`.  I added this key value pair `'class_submit' => 'button white',` to the array on the variable `$comment _form`.  This could be different depending on your theme.